# Match one of multiple specific values in input field using the pattern attribute

Tags: javascript, regex, html, validation

I want a user to enter only one of these: 0, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2, 2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3, 4 and 5 and must be validated using the pattern attribute. My code is like this:

```html
<input class="grade-field" type="text" maxlength="4" pattern="[0-5]+(\.\d*)?" value="0">
```

Right now it accepts numbers anywhere from 0-5.99 only. I'm not very familiar with matching using regex so I know I'm definitely wrong here. If I enter 1.34 it is a valid input and will proceed.

Comment: why not use a select with apropriate options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply OR the values you want with '|' like this:

```
^(0|1|1\.25|1\.5|1\.75|2|2\.25|2\.5|2\.75|3|4|5)$
```

That should give you the right test answer.

EDIT: I forgot dots must be escaped, try the new one.

Comment: Thanks dude but there's a little problem. 0,1,2,3,4,5 works perfectly except for 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2.25, 2.5 and 2.75.

Answer (score 1):

Solution given by [Poul Bak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36111225/match-one-of-multiple-specific-values-in-input-field-using-the-pattern-attribute/36111262#36111262) is correct. Nothing wrong with that.

But I tried to make it more shorter. This might seem a little complex but if you take a closer look it makes sense why I made it short.

**Regex:** `^([0345]|[12](\.([27]?5))?)$`

**Explanation:**

- Using character class `[0345]` we are matching either of them literally.
- Let's break this one down: `[12](\.([27]?5))?`

  - `[12]` matches `1` and `2` literally.
  - `(\.([27]?5))?` is the optional decimal part for numbers with decimal part.

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pV8hS9/4)**</kbd>